# Metaplex: Verifying Collection and Creator in bulk

Tags: solana, metaplex

I found out that metaplex provides a function to verify collection and creator for a single nft, but I would like to know if there is a way to flip the collection and creator's verified flag to 1 for around 10K NFT's in a single transaction?

I also went through https://collections.metaplex.com/ , it requires to create a new collection and share the list of NFT's , but in my case the Collection NFT is already minted and configured in each NFT's, I just need to mark the collection and creator address as verified

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a limit to instructions in a transaction (I think they are working on increasing it). I have seen a maximum of 20 verify instructions in one transaction.